# matplotlib, scale/skip "part" of the axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

In matplotlib is there a way to "scale" one part of the axis so that (say) the values 0....200 take as much space as 200 to 210?

And if scaling is impossible is there a way to skip all numbers between 5 & 195 then?

I prefer scaling as that would keep continuous functions continuous (and for my application for low numbers it is only important to know that the functions are continuous/that they're quadratic or linear).

Comment: Are you looking for a log scaling?  `ax.set_xscale('log')`

Comment: You can also write custom scales, see `matplotlib.scale`

Comment: @tcaswell actually not a logarithmic scale, as that would put more stress on the early numbers, while crunching the higher numbers.